# Gray out a form row's (detail's) button conditionally with VBA code

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, events

I have a standard form in MS-Access which lists a bunch of orders, and each row contains order no, customer, etc fields + a button to view notes and attached document files.

On request from our customer we should gray out the button `btnAnm` (or check or uncheck a checkbox) depending on a calculation from two queries to two other tables (a SELECT COUNT WHERE and a check if a text field is empty).

I've tried `btnAnm_BeforeUpdate(...)` and `btnAnm_BeforeRender(...)` and put breakpoints in the subs, but none of them trigger. The same if I use the control `Ordernr` instead of `btnAnm`.

I'd like a function in the Detail VBA code to be triggered for each "`Me.`" (row) so to speak, and set the row's control's properties in that sub.

What do I do? I've looked at the help file and searched here.

*Edit: So I want to do something that "isn't made to work that way"? Ie. events are not triggered in Details.
As an alternative, could I base the value of a checkbox on each line on a query based on the 'Ordernr' field of the current row and the result of a SELECT COUNT from another table and empty field check?

Do I do this in the query the list is based on, or can I bind the extra checkbox field to a query?

A description of how to do this (combine a COUNT and a WHERE "not empty" to yes/no checkbox value) would be perfectly acceptable, I think! :)*

Comment: could you show some code? especially where you want to trigger the code

Comment: Where to put the code so it gets triggered for each detail row is what I am (was?) asking, the code is btnAnm.ForeColor=0 right now... ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do much with an unbound control in a continuous form, anything you do will only apply to the current record. You can use a bound control with a click event so that it acts like a button.

Presumably the related documents have a reference to the order number that appears on your form, which means that you can create a control, let us call it CountOrders, with a ControlSource like so:

```
=DCount("OrderID","QueryName","OrderID=" & [OrderID])
```

The control can be hidden, or you can set it up to return true or False for use with a textbox, you can also use it for Conditional Formatting, but sadly, not for command buttons.

```
Expression Is [CountOrders]>0
```

You can also hide the contents and add a click event so that is acts in place of the command button. Conditional Formatting will allow you to enable or disable a textbox.

Comment: I'm perfectly happy with just 'marking' the row somehow as a result from the two queries, changing some element's color or setting a checkbox's value, on that row. It's marked in order for the user to know if there are notes/documents to read attached to the order.

Comment: @Henrik I have added a few notes.

Comment: Indeed an additional control+control source is required, in our case having a nearby checkbox instead of graying out the button was acceptable to the customer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As I understand your question, you have a continuous form with as command button that appears on each row - and you'd like to enable/disable the button conditionally depending on the contents of the row.

Unfortunately you can't do that. It seems that you can't reference the individual command buttons separately.

Having wanted to do something similar in the past I came up with two alternate ways of setting up my interface.

1. Put a trap into the onClick code for the Button. Which is icky, because it is counter intuitive to the user. But it gets you that functionality now.
2. Move the command button (and editable fields) up into the form header, and make the rows read only. Your users then interact with the record only in the header, and select the record they want work with in the list below. As I recall this is known a Master-Detail interface.

Comment: It's a form with header, repeated detail, and footer. Re. 1, that's just it. Having something clickable that tells you if it's clickable (non empty) is as bad as showing the empty order form, which is what I want to prevent. Re. 2,changing the UI is not an option right now.

Comment: Re #1 - as I said - it's icky. Re: #2 - every technology has its limitations, this is one of them.